# Pattern coding in Java

Tags: java

I trying to solve the below pattern in java. But unable get proper output.

**INPUT**:

```
4
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
bbb*bbb
bb*i*bb
b*iii*b
```

**Code**:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int n, m, j, k, l, p, o = 0;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = s.nextInt();
        for (m = 1; m <= n; m++) {
            for (j = m; j < n; j++) {
                System.out.print("b");
            }

            for (k = 2; k < 2 * m + 1; k++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            for (o = 3; o < m + 2; o++) {
                System.out.print("i");
            }
            for (p = 3; p < m + 2; p++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            for (l = m; l < n; l++) {
                System.out.print("b");
            }
            System.out.println();

        }
    }
}
```

**Getting Output**:

```
bbbb*bbbb
bbb***i*bbb
bb*****ii**bb
b*******iii***b
*********iiii****
```

Comment: I suggest that you look at each of your loops, think about how many symbols you want them to produce, and ask yourself whether that loop could possibly produce the right number of symbols. If you don't think it can, or the output proves that it isn't, try to come up with a loop that will produce the correct number of symbols.

Comment: Could you give more examples of input/output behavior? For example, does `n = 2` output `b*b` and `n = 3` output `bb*bb` and `b*i*b`? What does `n = 1` output? `b`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So

- there is en extra line
- the `*` is always one, don't need a loop
- the `i` should use `row*2` as bound

```java
for (row = 0; row < n - 1; row++) {
    for (j = row; j < n - 1; j++) {
        System.out.print("b");
    }
    // always
    System.out.print("*");
    for (i = 1; i < row * 2; i++) {
        System.out.print("i");
    }
    if (row != 0) { // except first line
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    for (k = row; k < n - 1; k++) {
        System.out.print("b");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

---

Using `String.repeat`

```java
for (row = 0; row < n - 1; row++) {
    String b = "b".repeat(n - 1 - row);
    String i = "i".repeat(Math.max(0, row * 2 - 1));
    System.out.println(b + "*" + i + (row != 0 ? "*" : "") + b);
}
```